# Xamarin forms setting SelectedItem property in ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

This may be just a silly mistake but I cant find a similar issue
In my xaml I have the code below

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Consumers}" 
                BackgroundColor="#262828" 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HeightRequest="165"
                Margin="10"
                SeparatorColor="#505056"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsVisible="{Binding Consumers.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBool}, FallbackValue=false}"
                Grid.Row="1" 
               >
```

and in my ViewModel I have as given below

```
        private ObservableRangeCollection<ConsumerDetail> _consumers;

        public ObservableRangeCollection<ConsumerDetail> Consumers
        {
            get => _consumers;
            set => SetProperty(ref _consumers, value);
        }

       private ConsumerDetail _selectedItem;

        public ConsumerDetail SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
        }

        private void MoveSelectionDown()
        {
            if (Consumers.Count == 0) return;

            int index = Consumers.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

            if(index+1 == Consumers.Count - 1)
            {
                SelectedItem = Consumers[0];
                return;
            }

            SelectedItem = Consumers[index + 1];
        }
```

If you can see from the code I want to change SelectedItem from my ViewModel using its index using a method Up/Down

The code and the bindings does work, but after setting `SelectedItem = Consumers[index + 1];` or even with constant index `SelectedItem = Consumers[1];` in the UI it will select the next Item i.e. if I say SelectedItem = Consumers[1]; in the UI it will select ListViewItem Index 2 not 1 (the third row). But in debug SelectedItem is selecting to the correct Item (index = 1). I also confirm this by binding out the `SelectedItem.Field1` to a Label

This is only for android and need not consider other platform. Please help I have been struggling for a week now. Am I missing something? Is ListView to be accessed only from UI? Do I need to make a custom control to replicate ListView? Please guide me...

The app is to replicate an old POS handheld device where only numeric key and some special functions is needed for navigation and data entry. Kindly guide me since I am a novice in Xamarin forms. Thanks in advance

Added more code snippet in light of a quick help.
My Custom Control KeyPadCtrl code below

```
 private void Pad_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        string key = Convert.ToString(btn.ClassId);

        if (key.StartsWith("Num"))
        {
            Text = key.Replace("Num", "").TrimStart('0').WithRandom();
        }

        if (key.StartsWith("CTRL"))
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "CTRLBKSP":
                    ControlText = "CTRLBKSP".WithRandom();
                    return;

                case "CTRLCancel":
                    ControlText = "CTRLCancel".WithRandom();
                    return;

                case "CTRLEnter":
                    ControlText = "CTRLEnter".WithRandom();
                    return;
            }
        }

        if (key.StartsWith("F")) Function = key.WithRandom();
        
    }
```

Bindings with the custom control

```
 <custom:KeyPadCtrl Text="{Binding InputKey}" 
    NumLength="4"
    ControlText="{Binding ControlPressed}"
    Function="{Binding FunctionKey}" />
```

My BaseViewModel

```
       private string _inputKey;

        public string InputKey
        {
            get { return _inputKey; }
            set
            {

                if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                string modValue = value;
                modValue = modValue.Chop();

                if (IsAlert)
                {
                    int sw = Convert.ToInt32("0" + modValue[modValue.Length - 1]);
                    switch (sw)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            InputKeyContinue();
                            return;

                        case 2:
                            CloseAlert();
                            return;

                        default:
                            return;
                    }
                }


                SetProperty(ref _inputKey, modValue);
                OutputValue = (OutputValue + modValue).TrimStart('0');

            }
        }

        protected virtual void InputKeyContinue() { }

        private string _outputValue;

        public string OutputValue
        {
            get { return _outputValue; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _outputValue, value); }

        }

        public void CloseAlert()
        {
            IsAlert = false;
            AlertMsg = "";
            
        }

        private string _controlPressed = "";

        public string ControlPressed
        {
            get { return _controlPressed; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _controlPressed, value);

                if (value.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlcancel"))
                {
                    if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
                    return;
                }

                if (value.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlbksp"))
                {
                    if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                    OutputValue = OutputValue.BackSpace();
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        private string _functionKey;

        public string FunctionKey
        {
            get { return _functionKey; }
            set 
            { 
                SetProperty(ref _functionKey, value);
                FunctionKeyProcess(value);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void FunctionKeyProcess(string value) { }
```

And in my ViewModel this is how i process the KeyPadCtrl Properties

```
     private async void ReadingEntrySearchViewModel_PropertyChangedAsync(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(OutputValue))
            {
                ResultDisplay = OutputValue;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ControlPressed))
            {
                if (ControlPressed.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlenter"))
                {
                    List<ConsumerDetail> src = new List<ConsumerDetail>();
                    src = await ConsumerData.GetConsumers(ResultDisplay);

                    if (src.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        IsAlert = true;
                        AlertMsg = "Consumer not found";
                    }

                    Consumers.ReplaceRange(src);
                    
                    if (Consumers.Count > 0)
                    {
                        SelectedItem = Consumers[0];
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void FunctionKeyProcess(string value)
        {
            var vl = value.Chop();
           
            if (vl == "F2")
            {
                MoveSelectionUp();
   
            }

            if (vl == "F3")
            {
                MoveSelectionDown();
    
            }
        
        }
```

When debugging just as it finish the line `if (key.StartsWith("F")) Function = key.WithRandom();` in KeyPadCtrl the ListView visually will select the next item but not true in the background as mentioned earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code,I created a demo and did a test,but I couldn't reproduce this problem.

I added a button to `MainPage` to change the value of `SelectedItem` and bind to the command `TestCommand`  which is defined on the ViewModel.

You can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ConsumerDetail> _consumers;

        public ObservableCollection<ConsumerDetail> Consumers
        {
            get => _consumers;
            set => SetProperty(ref _consumers, value);
        }

        private ConsumerDetail _selectedItem;

        public ConsumerDetail SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
        }

        public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }


        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Consumers = new ObservableCollection<ConsumerDetail>();
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test1"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test2"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test3"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test4"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test5"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test6"});
            Consumers.Add(new ConsumerDetail { Name="test7"});

            // here I initialize the SelectedItem with Consumers[3]
            SelectedItem = Consumers[3];

            TestCommand = new Command(ChangeItem);

        }

        private void ChangeItem(object obj)
        {
            MoveSelectionDown();
        }

        private void MoveSelectionDown()
        {
            if (Consumers.Count == 0) return;

            int index = Consumers.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

        // the logic here is not valid ,please change it to the following code
           //if(index+1 == Consumers.Count - 1)
            if (index  == Consumers.Count - 1)
            {
                SelectedItem = Consumers[0];
                return;
            }

            SelectedItem = Consumers[index + 1];
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

**ConsumerDetail.cs**

```
public class ConsumerDetail 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:formlistapp2023="clr-namespace:FormListApp2023"
             x:Class="FormListApp2023.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formlistapp2023:MyViewModel></formlistapp2023:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Consumers}" 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HeightRequest="165"
                Margin="10"
                SeparatorColor="#505056"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
               >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="60" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>


        </ListView>

        <Button  Text="change selected item" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying this early. It never occurred to me to test it out on a clean project. Your code works perfectly. Now would you be so kind to help me figure out the culprit. I have a custom control **KeyPadCtrl** which is nothing but a bunch of numeric  buttons and some other buttons which are Bindable Properties namely TextProperty (pass digit by digit) , ControlTextProperty (pass Enter, Return, Cancel) and FunctionProperty. I had to create a virtual method in my BaseViewModel so that i can process every property. FunctionProperty calls the **MoveSelectionDown()** could it be the one?

Comment: Add to question the code that you now suspect might be the problem. But more importantly, start testing your code, to isolate the problem. If you comment out the call to MoveSelectionDown, does it work? If not, try other small changes to see what happens.

Comment: Hi @DavidLnt, could you please post more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT i dont know if its the rule but I edited my question and added more code snippet, can you please check it out

Comment: What's the full code of   `KeyPadCtrl ` and the viewmodel? And I didn't find the `SelectedItem` mentioned in your original question. This should be another problem. One problem, one thread. For this new problem, you can create a new thread and share the link here. We are all willing to help you. :)

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT here is the new post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322632/custom-keyboard-control-binding-and-controlling-listview-selecteditem-from-viewm) .. eagerly but patiently waiting :P