# Custom Keyboard Control binding and controlling ListView SelectedItem from ViewModel in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, viewmodel, custom-controls

This is a continuation of a problem with selecting item in a ListView from a ViewModel

[Click here to see starting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312590/xamarin-forms-setting-selecteditem-property-in-viewmodel)

I have a custom control KeyPadCtrl which will be used in all pages of my project.

The KeyPadCtrl will supply strings of **BindableProperties** Text, ControlText and Function that will be processed with BaseViewModel which can be different for every page.

On pressing F2 or F3 it selects **ListViewItem** UP or DOWN. But as of now it will select the next item for some reason. Please help me or guide me to identify and fix the problem.

I present full code below.

KeyPadCtrl XAML

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Reader_App.Custom_Controls.KeyPadCtrl"
             >

    <Grid Margin="50, 0, 50, 25" Padding="0">
 
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="33" />
            <RowDefinition Height="33" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BtnNumPadStyle">
                <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#1e1e1e" />-->
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#262828" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}">
                
            </Style>
            
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Text="F1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F1" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="F2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F2" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="F3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F3" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />
                                                                                      
        <Button Text="F4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F4" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="F5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F5" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="F6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  IsVisible="True" ClassId="F6" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" />

        <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="Num01" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num01" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="Num02" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num02" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="Num03" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num03" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />

        <Button Text="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Num04" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num04" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Num05" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num05" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="6" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Num06" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num06" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
                                                          
        <Button Text="7" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Num07" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num07" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="8" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Num08" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num08" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="9" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Num09" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num09" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />

        <Button Text="*" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Num00" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="Num00" Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />
        <Button Text="#" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"  Style="{StaticResource BtnNumPadStyle}" />


        <Button Text="X" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12" BackgroundColor="#de2121" 
                        x:Name="CTRLCancel" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="CTRLCancel" Padding="0"  />

        <Button Text="Back" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="10" BackgroundColor="#ddde21" TextColor="Black" 
                        x:Name="CTRLBKSP" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="CTRLBKSP" Padding="0" />

        <Button Text="Enter" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"  FontSize="10" BackgroundColor="#106f10"
                        x:Name="CTRLEnter" Clicked="Pad_Clicked" ClassId="CTRLEnter" />

    </Grid>
    

</ContentView>
```

KeyPadCtrl Code Behind

```
 public partial class KeyPadCtrl : ContentView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                 nameof(Text),
                 typeof(string),
                 typeof(KeyPadCtrl),
                 defaultValue:"0",
                 defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

        public static readonly BindableProperty NumLengthProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(NumLength),
                typeof(int),
                typeof(KeyPadCtrl),
                defaultValue: 8,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ControlTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(ControlText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(KeyPadCtrl),
                defaultValue: "",
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

        public static readonly BindableProperty FunctionProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Function),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(KeyPadCtrl),
                defaultValue: "",
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

 
        public int NumLength
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(NumLengthProperty);
            set => SetValue(NumLengthProperty, value);
        }

        public string Function
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(FunctionProperty);
            set => SetValue(FunctionProperty, Convert.ToString(value));
        }
        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, Convert.ToString(value));
        }

        public string ControlText {
            get => (string)GetValue(ControlTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(ControlTextProperty, Convert.ToString(value));
        }

        private string TempText = string.Empty;

        public KeyPadCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Pad_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            string key = Convert.ToString(btn.ClassId);

            if (key.StartsWith("Num"))
            {
                Text = key.Replace("Num", "").TrimStart('0').WithRandom();
            }

            if (key.StartsWith("CTRL"))
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case "CTRLBKSP":
                        ControlText = "CTRLBKSP".WithRandom();
                        return;

                    case "CTRLCancel":
                        ControlText = "CTRLCancel".WithRandom();
                        return;

                    case "CTRLEnter":
                        ControlText = "CTRLEnter".WithRandom();
                        return;
                }
            }

            if (key.StartsWith("F")) Function = key.WithRandom();
            
        }
    }
```

ReadingEntrySearchPage XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Reader_App.Custom_Controls" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Reader_App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Reader_App.Views.ReadingEntrySearchPage"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Reader_App.Converters"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ReadingEntrySearchViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:CountToBoolConverter x:Key="CountToBool" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#1e1e1e" Margin="0" Padding="0,15,0,0" >
                <Label Text="ENTER CONSUMER NO" FontSize="Large"  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <custom:NumericLabel Margin="20"  
                                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                     Text="{Binding ResultDisplay}" 
                                     NumLength="4"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding TempInt}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ConsumerNo}" TextColor="White"/>
                <Button Text="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Consumers}" 
                BackgroundColor="#262828" 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HeightRequest="170"
                Margin="15"
                SeparatorColor="#505056"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsVisible="{Binding Consumers.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBool}, FallbackValue=false}"
                Grid.Row="1" 
               >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10, 5 , 5, 5" >
                            <StackLayout.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Label" >
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                                    
                                </Style>
                            </StackLayout.Resources>

                            <Grid BackgroundColor="#262828" >
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto" />
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*" />

                                <Grid RowDefinitions="auto" />
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="auto" />

                                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >

                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="#424346"
                                         CornerRadius="10"
                                         Margin="10,0,0,0" />

                                    <Label Text="{Binding ConsumerNo}"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        />
                                </Grid>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Cluster}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <custom:AlertCtrl 
            IsVisible="{Binding IsAlert}" 
            Text="{Binding AlertMsg}" 
            AlertType="{Binding AlertType}"
            Grid.Row="0" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Vertical">

        <custom:KeyPadCtrl Text="{Binding InputKey}" 
                           NumLength="4"
                           ControlText="{Binding ControlPressed}"
                           Function="{Binding FunctionKey, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                            />
        </StackLayout>


    </Grid>
    
</ContentPage>
```

ReadingEntrySearchViewModel

```
public class ReadingEntrySearchViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private readonly IConsumerMockData ConsumerData;
        public Command TestCommand { get; }

        public ReadingEntrySearchViewModel()
        {
            AlertType = AlertType.OkOnly;

            ConsumerData = DependencyService.Get<IConsumerMockData>();

            PropertyChanged += ReadingEntrySearchViewModel_PropertyChangedAsync;

            Consumers = new ObservableRangeCollection<ConsumerDetail>();
            TestCommand = new Command(TestMethod);
        }

        private void TestMethod()
        {
            SelectedItem = Consumers[1];
        }

        private async void ReadingEntrySearchViewModel_PropertyChangedAsync(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(OutputValue))
            {
                ResultDisplay = OutputValue;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ControlPressed))
            {
                if (ControlPressed.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlenter"))
                {
                    List<ConsumerDetail> src = new List<ConsumerDetail>();
                    src = await ConsumerData.GetConsumers(ResultDisplay);

                    if (src.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        IsAlert = true;
                        AlertMsg = "Consumer not found";
                    }

                    Consumers.ReplaceRange(src);
                    
                    if (Consumers.Count > 0)
                    {
                        SelectedItem = Consumers[0];
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableRangeCollection<ConsumerDetail> _consumers;

        public ObservableRangeCollection<ConsumerDetail> Consumers
        {
            get => _consumers;
            set => SetProperty(ref _consumers, value);
        }

        private ConsumerDetail _selectedItem;

        public ConsumerDetail SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
        }

        protected override void InputKeyContinue()
        {
            //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ReadingEntryPage)}");
            CloseAlert();
        }

        protected override void FunctionKeyProcess(string value)
        {
            var vl = value.Chop();
           
            if (vl == "F2")
            {
                MoveSelectionUp();
            }

            if (vl == "F3")
            {
                MoveSelectionDown();
            }
        }

        private void MoveSelectionUp()
        {

            if (Consumers.Count == 0) return;

            int index = Consumers.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

            if (index == 0)
            {
                SelectedItem = Consumers[Consumers.Count-1];

                return;
            }

            SelectedItem = Consumers[index - 1];
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));

        }

        private void MoveSelectionDown()
        {
            if (Consumers.Count == 0) return;

            int index = Consumers.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

            if(index == Consumers.Count - 1)
            {
                SelectedItem = Consumers[0];
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));

                return;
            }

            SelectedItem = Consumers[index + 1];
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }

        private string _resultDisplay = string.Empty;

        public string ResultDisplay
        {
            get => _resultDisplay;
            set => SetProperty(ref _resultDisplay, value);
        }

        private int _tempInt;
        public int TempInt
        {
            get => _tempInt;
            set => SetProperty(ref _tempInt, value);
        }
    }
```

BaseViewModel

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
  

        bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => isBusy;
            set => SetProperty(ref isBusy, value);
        }

        string title = string.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
        }

        private int _maxKeyLenth;

        public int MaxKeyLength
        {
            get { return _maxKeyLenth; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _maxKeyLenth, value); }

        }

        private AlertType _alertType;

        public AlertType AlertType
        {
            get { return _alertType; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _alertType, value); }

        }

        private string _alertMsg;
        public string AlertMsg
        {
            get => _alertMsg;
            set => SetProperty(ref _alertMsg, value);
        }

        private bool _isAlert;

        public bool IsAlert
        {
            get { return _isAlert; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isAlert, value); }
        }

        private string _inputKey;

        public string InputKey
        {
            get { return _inputKey; }
            set
            {

                if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                string modValue = value.Chop();

                if (IsAlert)
                {
                    int sw = Convert.ToInt32("0" + modValue[modValue.Length - 1]);
                    switch (sw)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            InputKeyContinue();
                            return;

                        case 2:
                            CloseAlert();
                            return;

                        default:
                            return;
                    }
                }


                SetProperty(ref _inputKey, modValue);
                OutputValue = (OutputValue + modValue).TrimStart('0');

            }
        }

        protected virtual void InputKeyContinue() { }

        private string _outputValue;

        public string OutputValue
        {
            get { return _outputValue; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _outputValue, value); }

        }

        public void CloseAlert()
        {
            IsAlert = false;
            AlertMsg = "";
            
        }

        private string _controlPressed = "";

        public string ControlPressed
        {
            get { return _controlPressed; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _controlPressed, value);

                if (value.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlcancel"))
                {
                    if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
                    return;
                }

                if (value.ToLower().StartsWith("ctrlbksp"))
                {
                    if (IfAlertAndOkOnly) return;

                    OutputValue = OutputValue.BackSpace();
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        private string _functionKey;

        public string FunctionKey
        {
            get { return _functionKey; }
            set 
            { 
                SetProperty(ref _functionKey, value);
                FunctionKeyProcess(value);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void FunctionKeyProcess(string value) { }

        private bool IfAlertAndOkOnly
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsAlert && AlertType == AlertType.OkOnly)
                {
                    CloseAlert();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        
    }
```

ConsumerDetail Model

```
    public class ConsumerDetail
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ConsumerNo { get; set; }
        public string Cluster { get; set; }
        public string MeterNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
    }
```

I tried without **KeyPadCtrl ** it works seamlessly but **KeyPadCtrl ** is the main navigation and controller for every page and i need it to work. From my many debug i cannot see where the extra UI SelectedItem changed. Kindly guide and help me fix the bug

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I see there is a fair amount to this; ignore the bot - but its too much to spot a problem just reading it. I recommend making a `public github repo` that can be run to see the problem. Include or hardcode any needed data, so repo is self-contained. Add link to that repo at end of your question.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve will do, will extract the part and share the link. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

For unknown reason

```
public static string WithRandom(this string value)

 {

 Random random = new Random();

string characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
 int length = 10;

 string randomString = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(characters, length)
                     .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

 return value + "|" + randomString;

 }
```

in StringExtension.cs was the culprit while sending Key Codes from KeyPadCtrl it somehow trigger extra movement in the UI. Thanks for all the support guys